# Check for not existing record

Tags: sql, postgresql

I want to select all the records for which a condition is true, or that don't exist

I have something like this

```
select * 
  from trackings
 where field = 'domain' and string_value is null
    or *dont exist at all* -- <- Here is the troubled condition
```

What's the proper way to handle this

Comment: Can you show some sample data?

Comment: what do you mean by 'dont exist at all'? is it an entire field or a particular data?

Comment: **[EDIT]** your question and add some sample data and the expected output based on that data. [**Formatted**](http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help#code) **text** please, [no screen shots](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-may-i-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557)

Comment: If it doesn't exist at all, how do you want to select it ?

Comment: Heh, you cannot select something that does not exist. Probably you menat records where some field (column) data does not exist. Or you may have one table and search for records that do not exist in another related table, that has sense. This is not clear question what you want to achieve.

Answer (score 1):

Are you looking for [exists](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/functions-subquery.html)?

```
select * from trackings
 where (field = 'domain' and string_value is null) or
        not exists (select 1 --TODO: put the right sql which should return an empty cursor
                      from trackings t
                     where t.field = 'domain' and 
                           t.string_value is null)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT * 
  FROM trackings
 WHERE (field = 'domain' 
   AND  string_value is null)
    OR (1 = 1)
```

Comment: `or( 1=1)` cancels `(field = 'domain' and string_value is null)` and you'll get *all* the records